# How to copy files from a SSH into a Google Cloud Repo

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, deployment, bitbucket, gcloud

I could not use the "gcloud app deploy" inside of a SSH, so now I need to grab those files and bring them into my Google repo (my project) then deploy so I create the website with the files (that include the html used for the website). Here is what the files look like inside the SSH:

```
jinthemix@cloudshell:~ (website-deploying-gc)$ ssh jinthemix@vergil.u.washington.edu
Password: _
Last login: Wed Jan 20 20:20:45 2021 from 157.119.197.35.bc.googleusercontent.com


vergil11$ ls
GITREPOS  IMD233  Mix 1  Mix 2  Mix 3  Mix 4  Files  public_html  README.md  websitedeployinggc
vergil11$ cd Files
vergil11$ cd websitegc
vergil11$ ls
app.yaml  IMD233  Files  README.md  www
vergil11$
```

And here is what the google cloud looks like (there is no files besides the one already in here):

```
jinthemix@cloudshell:~ (website-deploying-gc)$ ls
README-cloudshell.txt
jinthemix@cloudshell:~ (website-deploying-gc)$
```

Any ideas on how copy the files into the google cloud project locally would help, thanks

Comment: You want to copy file from this server `vergil.u.washington.edu` to CloudShell?

Comment: Yes, I would like to copy files from the server (the ssh) into CloudShell

Comment: Specifically in the project indicated into the code (website-deploying-gc) (also next time I will just copy the files from Bitbucket into the project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`scp` command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html) from CloudShell

```
jinthemix@cloudshell:~ scp -r jinthemix@vergil.u.washington.edu:~/Files/websitegc/* .
```

This command uses OpenSSH to copy files between hosts on a network and with the help of the `-r` flag it will do it recursively with all the files and folders within the specified hosts.

Comment: So this copies all the files specifically from the Files folder into the project (website-deploying-gc)?

Comment: I am good with the question right now, thanks for the help, appreciated